# Error met on Crystax building Ceres

Tags: android, android-ndk, ceres-solver

When I was using Crystax ndk to build Ceres-Solver, I changed the

```
APP_STL := c++_static
```

to

```
APP_STL := gnustl_static
```

for gnustl_static is compatible with OpenCV on android, then I have the libceres.a, I copied it to the project jni folder and added the following line to Applications.mk

Then I run ndk-build using the Crystax ndk(I added the Crystax folder to the System PATH)

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += libceres.a
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += Test.cpp
```

a part of test.cpp using Ceres is as follows:

```
struct CostFunctor {
   template <typename T>
   bool operator()(const T* const x, T* residual) const {
     residual[0] = T(10.0) - x[0];
     return true;
   }
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  double x = 0.5;
  const double initial_x = x;

  Problem problem;

  CostFunction* cost_function =
      new AutoDiffCostFunction<CostFunctor, 1, 1>(new CostFunctor);
  problem.AddResidualBlock(cost_function, NULL, &x);

  Solver::Options options;
  options.minimizer_progress_to_stdout = true;
  Solver::Summary summary;
  Solve(options, &problem, &summary);

  return 0;
}
```

Then things goes **wrong**(the more error message is emitted):

```
/home/panxiaoyu/ceres-solver/jni/../internal/ceres/miniglog/glog/logging.h:174: error: undefined reference to 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_stringstream(std::_Ios_Openmode)'

/opt/crystax-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/5/include/bits/basic_string.h:544: error: undefined reference to 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringstream<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream()'

/opt/crystax-ndk/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/5/include/sstream:766: error: undefined reference to 'std::__cxx11::basic_stringbuf<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::str() const'
```

Where is wrong?

Is my ndk config wrong or the Crystax has an error?